# More efficient way of saving a dataset to SQL database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am looping through my dataset to save my database, I thought this might not be the best way. Is there a more resource efficient of doing it? Thanks.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To CO.Tables("CO_Del").Rows.Count - 1 'CO is my DataSet

    dbCommand.Parameters.Clear()

    AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@IsDelete", DbType.Boolean, 0, DBNull.Value)
    dbCommand.Parameters("@IsDelete").Value = True

    AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@IsUpdate", DbType.Boolean, 0, DBNull.Value)
    dbCommand.Parameters("@IsUpdate").Value = False

    AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@Out_Code", DbType.String, 50, DBNull.Value)
    dbCommand.Parameters("@CO_Code").Value = CO.Tables("CO_Del").Rows(i).Item(0).ToString

    ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand)

Next i
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your above code does, but you normally only need to call [SqlDataAdapter.Update(DataSet)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx) to update all changed rows in your DataSet's Table. If there are more than one, you could iterate all tables and call `DataAdapter.Update(Table)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GetChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/a4ey25we%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method. Saves you alot of looping.
Its also cool to reset value if invalid and Finally 'AcceptChanges' to continue your work without rebinding

Answer (score 0):

See [SQLBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx). It's very fast and works great for performing bulk updates.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have here two options for this issue: [TableAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171933.aspx) or SqlDataAdapter.
I'll prefer TableAdapter, because it use type safe dataset. TableAdapters typically contain Fill and Update methods to fetch and update data in a database.